# Converting dtype('O') to a date DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: pandas, object, data-conversion

im a begginer at coding and started a project for my small business.

i imported a xlsx file using panda and got the table with dtype('O') at every columns

[me sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD0hf.png)

but i can't find anywhere a way to get only the date in the format DD/MM/YYYY

any tips?

i have tried this code

```
tabela['dt_nasc'] = pd.to_datetime(tabela['dt_nasc'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

but the results were

```
ValueError: time data '1988-10-24 00:00:00' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)
```

i also tried another code

```
import datetime
def convert_to_date(x):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(x , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    tabela.loc[:, 'dt_nasc'] = tabela['dt_nasc'].apply(convert_to_date)
    
    # better to use a lambda function
    tabela.loc[:, 'dt_nasc'] = tabela['dt_nasc'].apply(lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

but couldn't find a way to print at format DD/MM/YYYY

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
s = pd.Series({0: '2022-11-29 13:00:00', 1: '2022-11-30 13:48:00'})
```

`s`

```
0    2022-11-29 13:00:00
1    2022-11-30 13:48:00
dtype: object <-- chk dtype
```

---

**Code**

object to datetime

```
pd.to_datetime(s)
```

`result`

```
0   2022-11-29 13:00:00
1   2022-11-30 13:48:00
dtype: datetime64[ns] <--chk dtype
```

convert `result` to DD-MM-YYYY HH-mm-ss

```
pd.to_datetime(s).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

0    16-11-2022 13:00:00
1    17-11-2022 13:48:00
dtype: object <--chk dtype
```

convert `result` to DD/MM/YYYY

```
pd.to_datetime(s).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

0    29/11/2022
1    30/11/2022
dtype: object <-- chk dtype
```

Comment: thanks for help, but it does not work.

s = tabela['dt_nasc']
pd.to_datetime(s)
s.dtype

i tried to follow yours steps, but got the error below:

ParserError: String does not contain a date:

Comment: @LucasBorges Even if provide current code, there are people who can't apply it. This happens with people who ask questions without making example. That's why people don't answer questions without examples. make example like me not image : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example